# Solve Harmonic Oscillation and Radioactive Decay differential equations with boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, boundary-value-problem

Could you give me your feedback ? We have no solutions to this exercise

---

Given are the two differential equations with boundary conditions

1. $m \ddot x = -Dx$ with $\dot x(0) = 0$. Determine $x = x(t)$
2. $\dot N = \lambda N$ with $N(0) = N_0$. Determine $N = N(t)$

---

1. $ \ddot x = -D/m \cdot x$ With $\dot x(0) = 0$, we know that $x(t) = \cos{(\sqrt{(D/m)} 
 \cdot t)} + C$ 
2. We can see directly $N(t) = N_0 \cdot e^{\lambda t} $.

For ODE 2, we have $C=0$ because $N(0) = N_0$, while in ODE 1, the boundary condition $\dot x(0) = 0$ is with the derivative so we have no idea about the value of the constant $C$ in the first ODE because the derivative of a constant is zero

First ODE is the Harmonic Oscillation, and the second ODE is the radioactive decay

---

What is correct and what could be improved ? Thanks for your feedback !

Comment: The first one is incorrect. Try filling in your "solution" into the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding ODE 1)  We have a second-order ODE, so we have two constants, but only one boundary condition.  So, there will be one undetermined constant.

The general solution:
$x'' = - \frac {D}{m} x$
$x = A\cos (\sqrt {\frac Dm}\ x-\phi)$
Or
$x = A\cos (\sqrt {\frac Dm}\ x) + B\sin (\sqrt {\frac Dm}\ x)$

Either one is fine they are in fact equal to one another, depending on your choices of $A, B,$ and $\phi,$ but I prefer the second form.

The boundary condition of $x'(0) = 0$ tells you that $B = 0$ or $\phi = 0$ depending on which solution you go with.